# Apache2 - ServerAlias not working

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to get the site working properly without the "www" addition.
[www.roeldevries.me](http://www.roeldevries.me) works fine, but [roeldevries.me](http://roeldevries.me) gives an other result.

Can someone help me?

/etc/apache2/sites-available roeldevries.me config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName roeldevries.me
 ServerAlias www.roeldevries.me
 DocumentRoot /var/www/roeldevries.me/public_html
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/roeldevries.me/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/ hosts config

```
127.0.1.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   roeldevries.me www.roeldevries.me

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What do your logs say? Have you restarted apache after making the changes to the config file? What does `httpd -S` show?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using Ubuntu. The command returns a "bad user name $(APACHE_RUN_USER) error. I indeed restarted apache several times by now trying to get it all working.

Comment: Run the command using sudo.

Comment: I get the same result, still a bad user name. Also tried with the root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- symlink sites-available to sites-enabled
  `a2ensite roeldevries.me`
- test config
  `apachectl -t`
- then 
  `apachectl restart`

if apachectl -t errors, post them.

also show contents of sites-enabled `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`
 , disable `a2dissite` any extra site not in use.

Personally, I do not use the same IP for my root domain as I do my real domain, example.

`jacobdevans.com IN A 198.251.86.133` ;[Anycast 301](http://www.jacobdevans.com/anycast-301/)

`www.jacobdevans.com IN NS coco.ns.cloudflare.com.
www.jacobdevans.com IN NS guy.ns.cloudflare.com.`

Comment: no problem!  I would still suggest (for SEO) you 301 your non-www to www.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to specify domain in hosts file as 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 - remove it and use `ServerName localhost.localdomain`. You've got `VirtualHost *:80` - that's enough.

This MUST work and WILL WORK. Only reason to not to will be the site config, which probably looks at the domain you are visiting. That's the only possible thing.

Comment: he doesn't NEED to remove it...